# How to Host 2 websites on one domain name

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have a website A, it is hosted on `www.abcde.com`. It works fine.

I have another website B, and I want it to be hosted at `www.abcde.com/efg/`

Website B is a separate website, it has its own web.config file and is stored in different folder.

Do you guys have any clue of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) `efg` directory to an application and it will work just fine.

`efg\Web.config` will override all settings from `<root>\Web.config`.

Comment: The biggest problem with this is that EFG inherits everything from the root site. You can run in to issues where you have to add special config values to the EFG application to remove those base config values from your project. These can be Authentication, HTTP Modules, Helpers, Namespaces, etc. Godaddy commonly (or at least they use to ) forces you to do this type of setup when you have X domains hosted under one hosting account. The issue isn't with answer that abatishchev gave but more so with how things inherit.

Comment: @NickBork,@abatishchev  Thank you for answering. I still prefer putting them in different folders. I will try your solution if there're not other ways.